# Micronaut Random Port fails to start Tests

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-rest

I maintain quite a big micronaut application with thousands of tests. Recently I've migrated to Azure and start seeing these flaky tests with this error

```
Test initializationError FAILED

io.micronaut.http.server.exceptions.ServerStartupException: Unable to start Micronaut server on port: 43218
```

application-test.yml

```
---
micronaut:
  server:
    port: ${random.port}
```

example Test

```
@MicronautTest 
class MathServiceSpec extends Specification {

   @Inject
   MathService mathService 

   @Unroll
   void "should compute #num times 4"() { 
       when:
       def result = mathService.compute(num)

       then:
       result == expected

       where:
       num | expected
       2   | 8
       3   | 12
   }
```

I can't see any obvious reason why micronaut picks a port in use for the random.port, or why this only started happening after migrating to Azure as there is no obvious connection I can make.

Comment: By default, tests marked with `@MicronautTest` will start on a random available port.  I would expect the config you have to work but if you remove the `micronaut.server.port: ${random.port}` setting, does the problem persist?

Comment: will give it a try. The worst bit about this is that 500 tests run, 1 fails and it breaks my CI/CD pipeline. So 499 times that random worked fine and we've never seen this error in AWS

Comment: "The worst bit about this is that 500 tests run, 1 fails and it breaks my CI/CD pipeline" - Has there been any investigation into what it is that is bound to the port that Netty is trying to bind to?

Comment: happens with different ports. e.g io.micronaut.http.server.exceptions.ServerStartupException: Unable to start Micronaut server on port: 43218
Googling that port there is nothing that uses it normally

Comment: Did the problem persist after removing `micronaut.server.port: ${random.port}`?

Comment: Removing that setting is a good idea and should be done regardless of whether or not it fixes the problem described in the question.  If you make that change and can share whether or not that addressed the problem, that would be valuable feedback.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yes, I've now posted why this happened, a workaround for this bug is on the Azure pipeline set autoCancel: false; as a result the port won't be closing when the new pipeline starts so micronaut will not fail to get a free port

Comment: "yes, I've now posted why this happened" @RiughaAr - Is your "yes" there an answer to "Did the problem persist after removing `micronaut.server.port: ${random.port}`?

Comment: yes the yes was because the problem persists after removing the random.port
This was amazingly difficult to test but I'm pretty confident Micronaut is picking ports that are being used by processes that are being killed or that should be dead but are not. Its pretty much a race condition

Comment: Your answer below says that Micronaut is using a deprecated `SocketUtils`.  Are you confusing `io.micronaut.core.io.socket.SocketUtils` with `org.springframework.util.SocketUtils`?  https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/5a8a7a7318d0f041f5fdfb667a9da5af1860a8e2/core/src/main/java/io/micronaut/core/io/socket/SocketUtils.java#L31 is not currently deprecated.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown its my understanding that micronaut SocketUtils is a copy of the deprecated Spring SocketUtils.

Comment: "its my understanding that micronaut SocketUtils is a copy of the deprecated Spring SocketUtils" - I did not realize that.  We will investigate.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues that would be helpful.  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I think some of the relevant code in Micronaut is at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/3.3.x/core/src/main/java/io/micronaut/core/io/socket/SocketUtils.java#L88-L95 and some of the relevant code for the now removed Spring one is at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/9f632cf0c1727e1b371e056aedc926d1b08e155c/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/SocketUtils.java#L199-L209.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems micronaut is using a depracated SocketUtils that is problematic
https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/5a8a7a7318d0f041f5fdfb667a9da5af1860a8e2/inject/src/main/java/io/micronaut/context/env/PropertySourcePropertyResolver.java#L595

Issue report from Spring
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28052

I'm confident this is the issue.

To clearly describe my problem:
Shortly after the gradle test task finishes, the ports start to get closed, but not immediately. This happens because of the autoCancel feature of my pipeline, as I've made another commit to that PR so my pipeline cancels the previous build. Because gradle deamon is forcibly killed ports stand a chance of being in use and micronaut picks up this ports as free because its using a copy of the Spring SocketUtils that is now deprecated exactly for this bug. Disabling the autoCancel works around this problem but means I need the build to finish to start the next build on the next commit basically wasting my time or build agents.

Comment: "I'm confident this is the issue" - Micronaut's `SocketUtils` is at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/5a8a7a7318d0f041f5fdfb667a9da5af1860a8e2/core/src/main/java/io/micronaut/core/io/socket/SocketUtils.java.  Are you saying that there was a bug in the Spring one that is also in the Micronaut one?

Comment: "Seems micronaut is using a depracated SocketUtils that is problematic"- The one at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/5a8a7a7318d0f041f5fdfb667a9da5af1860a8e2/core/src/main/java/io/micronaut/core/io/socket/SocketUtils.java is not currently deprecated.

Comment: Yes I'm saying the Spring one had a bug, that's why it was deprecated, please read the Spring report for it

Comment: I know the Spring one had a bug.  I am asking if the one in Micronaut has the bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
 micronaut:
  server:
    port: -1
```

solved the problem for me